# how increase the space between the bars of the column chart in wave dashboard of analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

Chart is created on compare table with SAQL modification.Can anybody please help with json modification required to obtain some space between the bars of the below chart??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set "autoFitMode": "fit" instead of "autoFitMode": "none"